# Persisting User Specific Settings in ASP.NET Server-Side

Tags: c#, asp.net, persistence

I'm working on a .NET 3.5 Web Application and I was wondering what would be good way to persist user specific settings (i.e. user preferences) server-side?

Here are the conditions:

- It needs to be able to store/retrieve
  settings based on a User ID
- I don't want to use SQL Server or any such DB engine
- I don't want to store it in cookies

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: If it makes any difference, it doesn't have to support a web farm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ASP.NET Profile feature for this. See [ASP.NET Profile Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx)

Comment: That was my first thought too but he mentioned no database engine.  Can the Profile Manager be configured to use text files instead of database?  If so, that is a good solution.

Comment: My read on Profile Manager was that it required a SqlProfileProvider.  This seems to specifically require a DB in which to create the profile tables; which, in turn, would require a DB engine.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/014bec1k.aspx. The Profile, Membership and Roles features of ASP.NET are all based on a provider architecture, meaning: you can use the same API, while storing the data however you like.

Comment: +1 Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.  It's the custom profile provider that allows me to store it in an XML file.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it off the bat. It was the basis for my thought about using Profile. I took it for granted that readers would know about the provider-based model of these components.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to persist data, and you don't want to use a database, then you need to save the data to disk (such as XML). If you're looking for something that isn't local to your server, you could use a SaaS solution that would host your data for you, such as [Amazon's S3 service](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/). If you do that, the latency of data retrieval will slow your application down, so you'll want to cache the data.

Answer (score 0):

Text files (JSON/XML/etc), though security then becomes an associated problem.

Answer (score 0):

Given those parameters, you could just keep track of your own user preferences XML file on the server.

Comment: This occured to me at first, but the idea of managing the XML via the XMLReader/Writer became rather unappealing.  This question seemed to address that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317134/